# How to Field Calculate only the values that aren't null?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, arcgis, esri

I'm using ArcPro, the field calculator. I want to populate a hydrant layer with hydrant inspection data.
I have two fields from a joined table: field 1 and field 2.  I want to populate field 1 with the values from field 2, but only if the values ARE NOT Null. Basically I want to preserve the values in field 1 if the corresponding value in field 2 is Null.  I've been trying slight variations of the python code below.  But it just populates field 1 with all of field 2 whether there are nulls or not.

Codeblock

```
def reclass(f1,f2):
        if f2 is not None:
            return f2
        else:
            pass
```

```
reclass(!field1!,!field2!)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Expression:

```
Reclass(!field1!,!field2!)
```

Codeblock:

```
 def Reclass(f1,f2):
        if f2 is None:
            return f1
        else: 
            return f2
```